# Mixin not able to deserialize the json

Tags: java, jackson, mixins

I am using mixin to deserialize json into POJO.
My POJO:

```
@Value.Immutable
@JsonDeserialize(as = ImmutableStatusResponse.class)
public interface StatusResponse {
    Status status();
}
```

Status is an enum class

```
public enum Status {
    PENDING,
    COMPLETED,
    CANCELLED
}
```

My Mixin class :

```
public abstract class StatusMixin {

    @JsonProperty("status")
    public abstract String getStatus();

    @JsonCreator
    public static Status getStatus(final String status) {
        Validate.notBlank(status);
        return switch (verificationStatus) {
            case "REQUESTED" -> Status.PENDING;
            case "DONE" -> Status.COMPLETED;
            default -> Status.CANCELLED;
        };
    }
```

I am using jackson for deserializing a json to the above response object
MAPPER.addMixIn(Status.class, StatusMixin.class);
But it is not able to deserialize

However if I am the switch statement in an overloaded getStatus method in Status enum then the deserialization is working ? What's the difference and how can i use my 1st approach

Comment: could you post the left code that you invoke and the source json